"nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'pod' not found
error:

"nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException:
Parameter 'pod' not found. Available parameters are [pods, startTime,
endTime, envId, param3, param4, param1, param2]"

code：
@Select("SELECT im.\*, po.id AS podId " +
"FROM instance_monitor im " +
"JOIN pod po ON im.name = po.name " +
"WHERE im.update_time BETWEEN #{startTime} AND #{endTime} " +
"  AND im.env_id = #{envId} " +
"  AND im.name IN  " +
"  \<foreach item='pod' index='index' collection='pods' open='(' separator=',' close=')'\>   " +
"    #{pod.podName} " +
"  \</foreach\>")
List\<InstanceMonitorDto\> getPodByName(@Param("pods")List\<Pod\> pods, @Param("startTime") LocalDateTime startTime, @Param("endTime") LocalDateTime endTime,
@Param("envId") Integer envId);

The foreach tag is used (copied from comment below):
" AND im.name IN " + 
" <foreach item='pod' index='index' collection='pods' open='(' separator=',' close=')'> " + 
" #{pod.podName} " + 
" </foreach>") 


The  tag is used:            "  AND im.name IN  " +
"   " +
"    #{pod.podName} " +
"  ")

The first bind value is List pods, but pods is never bound to the prepared statement above.

@曾廉洁 I have edited and formatted your question. Further  you can edit your question and include more details (as necessary).

@曾廉洁 To use <foreach> inside an annotation, you need to use <script>. See the doc.
